# HP Deskjet D1430 "Access Denied" During Install

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, installation, printer

I put a clean copy of Windows XP Pro on a Dell computer. After updating everything, and download the latest driver install program from HP, I eagerly install the printer.

Everything is fine and all, up until step 2 of 4 in the driver and program install, I am promoted with a cryptic "Access Denied" which halts installation. I have checked the HP knowledge base, and found a tool that would correct this problem for 90% of people. Guess who is in the 10%?

So how can I install this simple printer in Windows XP, this printer worked previously on this machine, also with the same version of Windows XP, flawlessly without any issues.

And Yes I am installing this program as a System Administrator, and running the setup file as the Administrator. I shouldn't be getting these messages. Help?

Comment: Anybody? Bueller? Bueller? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to install the driver manually through the device manager?

**[Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)** should be able to rip the installer.

*Unless someone really needs all the additional programs provided with the installer, this would be my preferred method to install HP printer/scanner drivers.*

Comment: Oh my GOD that program looks like what I needed! I shall try it right away.

Comment: ...and no I was looking for the barebones driver. I try to avoid bloatware :)

Comment: Except I couldn't extract the drivers :( it failed.

Comment: ...except on the third attempt it did! Got the driver file, printer is now installed. That is an awesome utility, and is being added to my "toolbelt" as we speak.

Comment: @Urda - yep, UniExtractor is quite handy, easy to rip installers and use programs 'portable'.

Comment: ***Unbelievably helpful*** is the Universal Extractor for resolving HP's much bug-infested driver download software.